# Update data controls whenever update occuer in SQL table

Tags: asp.net

my question is very simple .
say , I have a grid or combo box , its databounded with a table in sql server database.
I wish when ever there occur some update  in data table it refresh the grid .
I did it already with timer but doesn't it consuming resources by sending request after each time out ?
What are the possibilities in experts opinion to get this job done .

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to write some sort of Ajax type control that compares the TimeStamp of the last update when the grid loads to an Ajax or web service call that will return the TimeStamp of the last update/insert.  If they are not the same, then refresh your grid.  All web applications are stateless meaning that they do not retain state from call to call.  Real time controls in some way shape or other do something similar in its behavior depending upon the arhcitecture the control is built on.